# react relay login mutation not updating viewer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relay

i'm trying to add authentication to my app using jwt token. I've created a LoginMutation with the FIELDS_CHANGE type but it looks like relay doesn't hook it up with the existing model.
I've listed my relay mutation and schema mutation.

My LoginMutation:

```
import Relay from 'react-relay';

export default class LoginMutation extends Relay.Mutation {

  static fragments = {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
                id
      }
    `
  };

  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation{loginUser}`;
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on LoginPayload {
                viewer {
                    userId
                    email
                    password
                    jwt_token
                }
      }
    `;
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {
        viewer: this.props.viewer.id
      }
    }];
  }

  getVariables() {
    // inputs to the mutation
    return {
      email: this.props.credentials.email,
      password: this.props.credentials.password
    };
  }

  getOptimisticResponse() {
    return {
      viewer: {
                email: this.props.credentials.email
      }
    };
  }

}



const loginMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
    name: 'Login',
    inputFields: {
        email: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
        },
        password: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
        }
    },
    outputFields: {
        viewer: {
            type: userType,
            resolve: (user) => user
        }
    },
    mutateAndGetPayload: ({ email, password }, request) => {
        return getUserByCredentials(email, password)
            .then((user) => {
                if (!user) {
                    return newUser;
                }

                user.jwt_token = jwt.sign({
                    id: user.id,
                    name: user.name,
                    email: user.email
                }, JWT_SECRET);

                return user;
            })
            .catch((error) => { throw error; });
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you need toe add the changed fields (userId, email, password and jwt_token) also the the static fragment?

Comment: Why do you have in your static fragments property called `viewer` but the defined fragment is fragment on `User`? I assume that your `FIELDS_CHANGE` gets User ID instead of Viewer ID.

Comment: Having the same issue, so if you found a solution or found out it was impossible let me know! Also @LordDave i have my getVariables fragment query set to fragment on Viewer and still have the issue.